# svcutil.exe Error: The input read from 'serializer:DataContractSerializer' is inconsistent with other options

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization

I am trying to do Contract-First devlopment with WCF. I have the XSD schema. Now I am trying to generate the data contract. This following command is right out of the book, Microsoft Windows Communication Foundation 4.0 Cookbook for Developing SOA Applicationsbut it generates the error specified in the title. What am I doing wrong?

```
 C:\dev\GlobalwareQualityControlService\Schema>svcutil.exe /target:code /dataCont
ractOnly serializer:DataContractSerializer /importXmlTypes CarBookingRQ.xsd
```

Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: The input read from 'serializer:DataContractSerializer' is inconsistent w
ith other options.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that serializer needs a slash in front of it.